# Modified `regulatory.bin` not applying to `iw phy`

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I want to make my lapto into an access point with [`hostapd`](http://w1.fi/hostapd/) or [`airbase-ng`](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airbase-ng). Specifically, I want it to operate in 5 GHz band.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Kernel 3.16) is installed on my laptop and [Intel® Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300](http://www.intel.com/products/wireless/adapters/5000/) WiFi card is installed.

I learned that [Linux wireless regulatory](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory) defines country-specific regulation and lots of countries prohibits WiFi's 5 GHz operation. Hence, I modified `regulatory.bin` by following [this post](http://networkgeekstuff.com/networking/how-to-create-custom-linux-wi-fi-regulatory-database-to-unlock-30db1000mw/).

After rebooting, I can see modified regulatory.bin is applied (I've removed all restriction in **5250 - 5330 MHz band**):

```
$ iw reg get
country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20)
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0)
```

**However**, when I typed `iw phy`, it seems modified regulatory is not applied:

https://gist.github.com/gsongsong/01743e506d7e2cdd7c383473157b9521

Quoting only the important part in the result, it still shows:

```
* 5260 MHz [52] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
* 5280 MHz [56] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
* 5300 MHz [60] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
* 5320 MHz [64] (15.0 dBm) (passive scanning, no IBSS, radar detection)
```

Can anyone give me the reason that the modified regulatory does not seem to be applied?

I found [this thread](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-911400-postdays-0-postorder-asc-start-0.html) discussing about the same problem with me. But they are talking about Ahteros WiFi card (`ath9k` driver) and EEPROM, hence I wonder it is the very case that I am looking for.